# Rank within columns of 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, scipy

```
>>> a = array([[10, 50, 20, 30, 40],
...            [50, 30, 40, 20, 10],
...            [30, 20, 20, 10, 50]])

>>> some_np_expression(a)
array([[1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
       [3, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 2, 1, 3]])
```

What is `some_np_expression`? Don't care about how ties are settled so long as the ranks are distinct and sequential.

Answer (score 7):

Double argsort is a standard (but inefficient!) way to do this:

```
In [120]: a
Out[120]: 
array([[10, 50, 20, 30, 40],
       [50, 30, 40, 20, 10],
       [30, 20, 20, 10, 50]])

In [121]: a.argsort(axis=0).argsort(axis=0) + 1
Out[121]: 
array([[1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
       [3, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 2, 1, 3]])
```

With some more code, you can avoid sorting twice.  Note that I'm using a different `a` in the following:

```
In [262]: a
Out[262]: 
array([[30, 30, 10, 10],
       [10, 20, 20, 30],
       [20, 10, 30, 20]])
```

Call `argsort` once:

```
In [263]: s = a.argsort(axis=0)
```

Use `s` to construct the array of rankings:

```
In [264]: i = np.arange(a.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)

In [265]: j = np.arange(a.shape[1])

In [266]: ranked = np.empty_like(a, dtype=int)

In [267]: ranked[s, j] = i + 1

In [268]: ranked
Out[268]: 
array([[3, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 3, 2]])
```

Here's the less efficient (but more concise) version:

```
In [269]: a.argsort(axis=0).argsort(axis=0) + 1
Out[269]: 
array([[3, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 3, 2]])
```

Comment: Why do you need the _double_ `argsort`? `a.argsort(axis=0)+1` gives the same answer.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to use `rankdata` for this?  The best I can think of right now is `np.apply_along_axis(scipy.stats.rankdata, 0, a, method='ordinal')`.

Comment: @xnx: Trying ranking, say, `x = [30, 10, 20]`.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser That's interesting... but does it only apply to one-dimensonal arrays, though? In which case the column ranks should all be 1. Wouldn't `np.atleast_2d(a).argsort(axis=0)+1` be better?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the dimension, e.g. try ranking the columns of `a = np.array([[30, 50], [10, 30], [20, 20]])`.

Comment: Yup- I'm being dim. I understand how it works now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @DSM: An `axis` argument would be a nice enhancement to `scipy.stats.rankdata`.

Comment: Nice lesson in sorting! I'm off to translate this into `R` :-)

Comment: Update now Scipy offers rankdata function with support axis.

Answer (score 3):

Now Scipy offers a [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.rankdata.html) to rank data with an axis argument - you can set along what axis you want to rank the data.

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import rankdata    
a = array([[10, 50, 20, 30, 40],
           [50, 30, 40, 20, 10],
           [30, 20, 20, 10, 50]])

ranked_vertical = rankdata(a, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import rankdata
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[10, 50, 20, 30, 40],
              [50, 30, 40, 20, 10],
              [30, 20, 20, 10, 50]])

rank = (rankdata(a, axis=0)-1).astype(int)
```

The output will be as follows.

```
array([[0, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 2]])
```